# Angular 2 UI-Router Authentication

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, auth0, angular-router

I'm trying to implement JWT authentication in my angular 4 project. The server side is all set, only the front end need some extra work.

I found this [auth0/angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/tree/master#checking-authentication-to-hideshow-elements-and-handle-routing) library. But my concern is that I use ui-router in my project while the library seems to design for ngRoute (not sure). Does this UI-Router/ngRoute thing matter? Can I just use this library in my project?

Or is there any other authentication library that is designed for Angular 2/4 with UI-Router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for any routing preference you use. The general items you will consistently find yourself using is the 'tokenNotExpired' and of course the adding of the token to local storage and decoding it.

I have used this on half a dozen projects in production, and it can be as complex as you want (or as minimal, which is typically how I use it). `angular2-jwt` is a library that works perfectly for the handling of JWT in Angular 4+ projects as has always been well maintained.

**auth.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { tokenNotExpired, JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  _authChange: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  authChange = this._authChange.asObservable();

  constructor(private userService: UserService,
              private router: Router) { }

  login(emailAndPassword) {
    return this.userService.login(emailAndPassword)
    .map(
      res => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
        this._authChange.next(!this._authChange.getValue());
        return this.loggedIn;
      }
    );
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this._authChange.next(!this._authChange.getValue());
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  getUserName() {
    if ( this.loggedIn() ) {
      return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(localStorage.getItem('token')).user.username;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  getId() {
    if ( this.loggedIn() ) {
      return this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(localStorage.getItem('token')).user._id;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  isAuthChange(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authChange;
  }

}
```

**user.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  // Headers
  headers = new HttpHeaders()
              .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
              .set('charset', 'UTF-8' );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  register(user): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Attempting to insert user doc into tempuser collection');
    console.log (user);
    return this.http.post('/api/tempuser', JSON.stringify(user), { headers: this.headers }).timeout(1500);
  }

  login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('/api/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: this.headers });
  }

}
```

I provide both these services in the root `app.module`, and import `AuthService` in other components to access things like `authService.isLoggedIn()` to return a boolean if a user is logged in as well `authService.getUserName()` to return the user name as a string.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm gonna go with the angular2-jwt library. Just wonder if you have an example of how to implement it?

Comment: @Viv I pretty much go by their most basic examples of having an auth.service and a user.service. I'll go ahead and add how I handle these items to the answer.